# Problems using jQuery quicksand with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using this example of quicksand jQuery.

[Making a Beautiful HTML5 Portfolio](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/)

Now, i want to open light box when clicking on image. for this i am using fancybox jQuery. but the problem is in this Making a Beautiful HTML5 Portfolio(quicksand jQuery) example images are in `<Ul> <LI>` Tag, when in fancybox jQuery example have `<p>` Tag.

I am not able to select the anchor tag between ul li.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Making a Beautiful HTML5 Portfolio | Tutorialzine Demo</title>

        <!-- Our CSS stylesheet file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
        </script>

        <script src="assets/js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("a#example2").fancybox({
                    'overlayShow'   : false,
                    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
                });
                $("ul li a#example2").fancybox({
                    'overlayShow'   : false,
                    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
                });


            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
        </header>

        <nav id="filter"></nav>

        <section id="container">
        <p>
        <a id="example2" href="assets/img/shots/1.jpg"><img src="assets/img/shots/1.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <ul id="stage">
                <li data-tags="Print Design"><a id="example2" href="#"><img src="assets/img/shots/1.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/2.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Logo Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/3.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/4.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/5.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/6.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/7.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/8.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Logo Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/9.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/10.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/11.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/12.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/13.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Logo Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/14.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/15.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/16.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/17.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/18.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/19.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/20.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Web Design,Logo Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/21.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/22.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
                <li data-tags="Logo Design,Print Design"><img src="assets/img/shots/23.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></li>
            </ul>

        </section>

        <footer>
            <h2>Making a Beautiful HTML5 Portfolio</h2>
            <a class="tzine" href="http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/">Read &amp; Download on</a>
        </footer>



    </body>
</html>
```

in this code images in P tag working for fancy box but in ul li tags they aren't.

I think problem is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("a#example2").fancybox({
                        'overlayShow'   : false,
                        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
                    });
                    $("ul li a#example2").fancybox({
                        'overlayShow'   : false,
                        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
                    });


                });
    </script>
```

whole code http://fyels.in/Y95

Comment: Most people won't bother reading through so much code. If you can, try minimizing it to a level where the problem still exists, but the code is smaller.

Comment: @Amaan ohh then see the last code of jQuery selection, i wrote their this is main problem.

Comment: Is there a reason why you attempt to apply fancybox twice?

Comment: the first one is working for image <p>
        <a id="example2" href="assets/img/shots/1.jpg"><img src="assets/img/shots/1.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a>
        </p>   but second one is not working for images in <p>
            <ul id="stage">
                <li data-tags="Print Design"><a id="example2" href="#"><img src="assets/img/shots/1.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a></li></ul></p> Thats the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it.

The **main** reason fancybox didn't want to get along quicksand in your code is because of how quicksand plugin works. What quicksand does (in order to animate elements when reorganizing visible structure) is cloning the elements and injects copy of those into the DOM. Any events attached to those elements are gone after shuffling is done. This is why fancybox didn't work for those elements.

The way to fix this is described in [quicksand plugin documentation](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html) (section "Integration with other plugins"). It involves passing a callback function to quicksand as a second element. That callback will be executed once the shuffling is done, in our case it will be responsible for finding and re-applying fancybox to elements that were shuffled.

Here's **working example** of using quicksand with fancybox: http://jsfiddle.net/E2vLq/29/

Please note two things about the code:

- All links in the LI's have now class *fsand* (so we don't use same id over and over again).
- Passing the callback to quicksand that is re-applying fancybox to all elements that match `a.fsand` selector.

**Apart from that**, there were two other issues:

- Using same *id* for two elements on the same site (it is forbidden in general and according to html specs).
- You failed to close paragraph element after UL.

Comment: Your example not working here http://jsfiddle.net/wtk_pl/E2vLq/ for fancybox after clicking on image

Comment: Finally solved it  !!! Really nice solution(CLASS) given and explain by you. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

Reusing an id is invalid.  Try either

1. Using a different ID for the `a` in the `ul`
2. Using a different mechanism for referencing the element - e.g. use class

Comment: i have tried for different class also, let me try id for a in the ul. download my code from http://fyels.in/Y95 may you can help me better way